# How to wrap System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity> to a generic method?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

```
protected void saveform<T>(System.Data.Linq.Table<T> table, bool submit) 
    where T : class
{
    try
    {
        using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
        {
            var form = (from f in table
                        join r in dc.tbRecords on f.recordId equals r.recordId
                        where r.pID == pId
                        select new {f, r}).SingleOrDefault();
        ...
```

But I got this error message when compile :

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'recordId' and no extension
>   method 'recordId' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I handle this? 
Thanks.

Comment: T represents a row type, so restrict it to your type which has recordid public property

Comment: Are you sure you need generics for whatever you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, if I can go generic for saveForm(), I don't have to have this method for every form.

Comment: @sll if restrict it to specific type, then why generic?

Comment: I mean restrict T, `where T: IMyRow`

Comment: You _need_ to restrict it to rows having a recordId anyhow, right?

Comment: ...but I think Arran may be right - I'm not sure whatever you're trying to accomplish is best done this way.suffice?

Comment: @EamonNerbonne Please see my answer below, I have several forms have the same method - Save(), I don't want to repeat myself so I want to create the Save method on base class then pass the table parameter as generic type. I use reflection to saving data below.(not in the code)

Comment: .... I deleted my answer since multiple constrict is not right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you know that T has a 'recordId' property? It's only constrained to be an object...

A possible solution is to wrap your entities in an interface:

```
public interface IRecord
{
    public int recordId { get; }
}
```

You can use partial classes to make your entities implement this interface.

Then, constrain the generic type on your method to that interface, e.g.

```
protected void saveform<T>(System.Data.Linq.Table<T> table, bool submit) where T : IRecord
```